what's the different between TextStyle.merge and TextStyle.copyWith in flutter?
TextStyle.merge and TextStyle.copyWith have different descriptions but I seem to get the same result.
If merge behaves the same as copyWith, then there is no need for adding the method merge to TextStyle.Are there any differences between them?

class TestView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const baseStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16);
    final titleStyle = baseStyle.copyWith(
      color: Colors.red,
      decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
    ); // copyWith
    final noticeStyle = baseStyle.merge(const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.grey,
      decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
    )); // merge
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('this is title style', style: titleStyle),
        Text('this is notice style', style: noticeStyle),
      ],
    );
  }
}


You can choose "copyWith" when you want to specify individual properties to update and choose "merge" when you want to combine two instances of "TextStyle"

The different is the param you pass into it
If you already have an exist TextStyle then use merge:
final yourStyle = TextStyle().merge(existBaseTextStyle);

If you only need to change some properties, use copyWith():
final yourStyle = TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.red);


merge eventually call copyWith, so if other != null && other.inherit, they are no difference


In Flutter, TextStyle.merge and TextStyle.copyWith are methods used to create a new TextStyle object based on an existing one.
TextStyle.merge:

Returns a new text style that is a combination of this style and the given other style.
TextStyle.merge is used to merge two TextStyle objects into one.
style provides a value for an attribute (like color, fontWeight, etc.)

Example:
var firstTextStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: CUSTOM);
var secondTextStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 17);

var mergedBothStyle = firstTextStyle.merge(secondTextStyle );

TextStyle.copyWith :

Creates a copy of this text style but with the given fields replaced with the new values.
This method is useful when you want to make a copy of a TextStyle object with some modifications.

Example:
TextStyle baseStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black);
TextStyle modifiedStyle = baseStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.red);

